# Reactjs - State changes not rendering in dynamically created html table

Tags: reactjs, react-state

I'm having trouble displaying state changes. I put a link to my code below. You can see that when the user types in the input box that the inputs are not being displayed in the html table.

I thought that is because the "htmlRows" state variable reference doesn't change when the user types in the input box. So I added `setHtmlRows((o) => [...o]);` but that didn't work.

How can I dynamically create an html table and also show the changes from the formData state variable?

[Link to code on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-mipkuz?file=src%2FApp.js)

Comment: I'm not sure what you want. so if my answer is incorrect, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you want but I think you don't need to use `useEffect` hook.

For example:

```
function renderRows() {
  return (
    <tr>
      <td>The value will show here: {formData?.['thing']?.['foo']}</td>
    </tr>
  );
}

return (
  <div>
    <h1>The Value Shows Here: {formData?.['thing']?.['foo']}</h1>
    <input value={formData?.thing?.foo} onChange={inputHandler} />
    <table>
      <tbody>{renderRows()}</tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
);
```

You can see the whole example here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-is9rrt?file=src%2FApp.js